# Using fs.writeFile(), an array appears without square brackets or quote marks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For some reason, the array works differently when using fs.writeFile() as supposed to console.log(). Why do the quote marks and square brackets go missing?

```
word = args[0].split("")

//args is an array of the arguments the user writes in the discord command

//let's pretend that the word is: "test"

fs.writeFile('word.json', `{"word": ${word}}`, (err) => {

    if (err) {

    throw err
}

    console.log(`The word: "${args[0]}" has been saved`)
})

//writes {"word": t, e, s, t} giving a billion errors

console.log(word)

//outputs [ 't', 'e', 's', 't' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `word` is `['t', 'e', 's', 't']`.

So, when you do this:

```
`{"word": ${word}}`
```

The `${word}` syntax is attempting to convert the above array to a string so it calls `.toString()` on that array and that gives you:

```
t, e, s, t
```

So, your end result is:

```
{"money": t, e, s, t}
```

Which is all exactly as expected.

---

You don't show what you're really trying to do here, but the origin of this issue seems to be back here:

```
word = args[0].split("")
```

Where you're taking the first element of the `args` array and splitting it into an array of characters and that array of characters is not a string itself and appears to be the cause of your issue.

---

As a demo, you can see:

```js
console.log(['t', 'e', 's', 't'].toString())
```

Will give you:

```
 t, e, s, t
```

Whereas in this:

```js
console.log(['t', 'e', 's', 't']);
```

The `console.log()` looks at the type of the argument you passed it and uses type-specific logic for displaying it.  It does not just blindly call `.toString()` on it.  Instead, it displays it as the array that it is.

---

So, in the end the `${word}` syntax has different display rules than `console.log(word)` does.  Note, this has nothing to do with `fs.writeFile()` and has everything to do with how you prepare the data that you pass to `fs.writeFile()`.

Comment: this explains the issue, but im still wondering how _should_ i do it?

also, i accidentaly wrote "money" as the key instead of "word". thats because thats the word my friend tried to use.

Comment: @5akr1 - What result are you trying to end up with in the file?  Your question never says what the intended result is desired to be. If you're trying to create legal JSON syntax, then you should construct a Javascript object and call `JSON.stringify(obj)` on it to get your JSON string and put that in the file.

Comment: ```
        word.split("")

        let wordNew = "["

        for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

        wordNew += `"${word[i]}", `
        }

        wordNew.slice(1, -3)

        wordNew += "]"
```

worked for me, tho it's kind of a bodged together solution.